# Wordpress how to use custom query to get logged in users' post title?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have a custom post called 'project'.

I need to get 'titles' that logged in user wrote.

I tried the following code but it doesn't show any titles.

I'm a beginner... I looked into but I can't find which one has problems.

Would you please correct my code?

```php
function output_projects_list() {
  global $wpdb;

  $custom_post_type = 'project'; // define your custom post type slug here
  $current_user = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
  $current_user_name = $current_user->display_name;

  // A sql query to return all the logged in users' post titles 
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
SELECT ID
   , post_title 
FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
WHERE post_type = %s
 , author = %s"
 , and post_status = 'publish'
", $custom_post_type, $current_user_name ), ARRAY_A );

  // Return null if we found no results
  if ( ! $results )
      return;

  foreach( $results as $index => $post ) {
    $output = $post['post_title'];
  }
  return $output;
}
    
echo output_projects_list();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Wordpress can't see if a SPECIFIC user is logged in or not by default

Comment: Come on. You can see that this query is syntactically gibberish

Comment: Unless there is an obvious syntax error in the above code snippet, not we cannot tell you what's wrong eith your code! Why? Because things could have gone wrong at a dozen different places! You need to describe the error or unexpected behaviour in a greater detail to narrow the problem down to us! You should slso share sample data, query parameters and expected results with us.

Comment: If you are a beginner, then first solve the problem in MySQL. If you have a correctly working SQL statement (tested in i.e. phpMyAdmin), then you can start using this in PHP code.

Comment: I would recommend you start by learning to code PHP correctly. Then have a look at WordPress standards. http://developer.wordpress.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `WP_Query` instead, it's cleaner and easier to read. Take look at the following code:

```php
function user_published_posts()
{
  $query = new WP_Query(array(
    "author"        => get_current_user_id(),
    "post_type"     => "project",
    "post_status"   => "publish"
  ));

  while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    </a>
    <span><?php the_author() ?></span>
<?php };
}
```

Let me know if it's what you're looking for!

Comment: Hi Ruvee: Oh, Thank you again for your kind help. Yep, I will use WP_Query next time. I really learnt a lot from you. Oh, I left a text in the discussion box yesterday : )

Comment: @Aino Not a problem, i'm glad that i could help.